# Проблемы с вертикальной линией HTML

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Сегодня сделал на сайте вертикальную линию через `<div>`, но не могу изменить высоту. Как мне это сделать?
Код:

**CSS**:

```
.decoration {
   border-left:1px solid black;
   padding-left:10px;
    display:inline;
    width:4px;
    height: 100%;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="decoration"></div>
```

Comment: не inline, inline-block как минимум, а лучше block

Answer (score 0):

У тебя высота задана как % от родителя.
Либо меняй высоту родителя, либо используй px, vh .....

Comment: До процентов еще пробовал, не работает